# Solve $(x-a)^{\alpha +1} - \lambda*(b-x)^{\alpha + 1} = C(\frac{a+b}2 - x)^{\alpha}$ over $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

I have been having trouble solving the following equation. Any help would be appreciated.
Let a,b,C,$\alpha$,$\lambda$ be real numbers with $C < 0$, $0 < \alpha < 1$, $\lambda > 1$. We then look for a solution for the equation
\begin{equation}
(x-a)^{\alpha +1} - \lambda*(b-x)^{\alpha + 1} = C*(\frac{a+b}{2} - x)^{\alpha}.
\end{equation}
The variable is $x$ and we are looking for real solutions in the range $0 \leq x \leq (a+b)/2$.

Comment: upon defining $y=[(a+b)/2-x]/\Delta$, $\Delta=(b-a)/2$, $k=c/\Delta$, you can eliminate a few of the free parameters, leaving
$$(1-y)^{\alpha+1}-\lambda (1+y)^{\alpha+1}=k y^\alpha,\;\;0\leq y\leq 1.$$
There is no algebraic solution.

Comment: What do you mean that there is no algebraic solution?

Comment: you will have to solve it numerically.

Comment: but can one prove that there exists a solution?

Comment: there is no solution for sufficiently large $\lambda$, see the answer box.

Answer (score 2):

upon defining $y=[(a+b)/2-x]/\Delta$, $\Delta=(b-a)/2>0$, $k=C/\Delta<0$, you can eliminate a few of the free parameters, leaving
$$(1-y)^{\alpha+1}-\lambda (1+y)^{\alpha+1}-k y^\alpha=0,\;\;0\leq y\leq 1.$$

For general $\alpha\in(0,1)$ there is no closed-form solution, and there may be no real solution at all in the interval $[0,1]$.

In particular, if $\alpha\rightarrow 1$, the solution tends to $y\rightarrow (1+k/2)\pm\sqrt{k}\sqrt{4+k}$, which is imaginary for $-4<k<0$.

At the other extreme, if $\alpha\rightarrow 0$, the solution tends to $y\rightarrow \frac{1-k-\lambda}{1+\lambda}$ which is negative for $\lambda>1-k$.

More generally, for any $\alpha$ there will be no solution for large enough $\lambda$.

---

*Update:* the OP has [reposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/377211/11260) the question with the additional constraint that $k=-2\lambda(\alpha+1)$, so we seek the solution to
$$(1-y)^{\alpha + 1}-\lambda (y+1)^{\alpha + 1} + 2 \lambda (\alpha + 1) y^{\alpha} = 0.$$
For $\alpha\ll 1$ the solution is
$$y= \left(\frac{\lambda-1}{2 \lambda(\alpha+1)}\right)^{1/\alpha}.$$